# Synchrotron radiation and Hawking radiation

Tags: black-holes, radiation, hawking-radiation, synchrotron-radiation

According to 1 answer I came across:

> "There is a myth, for which Hawking himself is responsible, that
> Hawking radiation is primarily made up of matter-antimatter pair
> annihilation."

The simplest matter-antimatter pair I can think of is the electron-positron. From this, it can be inferred that Hawking radiation comes from annihilation between electrons and positrons. But if electrons are present in the black hole's magnetic field, it looks like synchrotron radiation may be present.So what happens when two such radiations are emitted?

Comment: As your quote says, it is a myth. So what are you trying to show right built on something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that Hawking both proposed the virtual particle interpretation in [the original paper](https://www.brainmaster.com/software/pubs/physics/Hawking%20Particle%20Creation.pdf), and immediately noted:

> It should be emphasized that these pictures of the mechanism
> responsible for the thermal emission and area decrease are heuristic
> only and should not be taken too literally.

What actually happens in this theory is an interaction between the black hole and surrounding quantum fields (whose excitations are particles). This process is essentially due to the observer-dependence of the number of particles in quantum fields under strong acceleration and happens even for uncharged black holes that do not have any magnetic field.

Actual astrophysical black holes are expected to be nearly uncharged (since they would attract opposite charges really well), but if they have an accretion disk this will cause strong magnetic fields from the outside to impinge on them, and their rapid rotation will then power up these fields even more. The resulting system is very complex but it is commonly theorized that there will be pair production due to strong fields and the presence of very energetic photons partially due to the plasma being hot, partially because of synchrotron acceleration of charged particles. This is normal pair production without the subtle (and perhaps non-literal) aspects of Hawking radiation.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to add that Hawking radiation is photons not electrons or positrons (except possibly in the final explosive evaporation if there is one).